# using call_form in menu forms 6i

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I am using forms 6i with 10g.

To call a form, I am using following code

```
call_form('frmtemp.fmx',no_hide);
```

window properties of form being called are as follow

```
window style = dialog
Modal        = No
```

If I call any form with a command button, it works fine, and no 2nd form can be displayed before existing first form , but
when form is called from menu with same code, we can call other forms.

What I need is, if I called one form from menu, no other form can be displayed.

regards.

Comment: Do you have any other logic in the command button logic? This because your described functionality doesn't seem to be the default Forms functionality. You usually can open another form on top of another form that have been opened with call_form.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the window property Modal to Yes instead of No.

Comment: by setting window property=yes of called form has no effect. what i need is that if one form has been called through MENU, after this even if user click MENU, no other form can be called or opened. regards.

Comment: I don't think there is any inbuilt Forms functionality for this kind of behaviour. You can though programmatically check if any other forms is opened. Don't remember that syntax but if you are interested I could try to dig for this kind of logic.